# How to display username from Firebase Realtime Database in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to display the current username from the Realtime Database but whenever I am running my code it gives me null. Here is my code:

```
    val reference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    currentUserUid = auth?.currentUser?.uid
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val username =
                dataSnapshot.child(auth!!.currentUser!!.uid).child("Users")
                    .child("username")
                    .getValue(String::class.java)
            if (username == null)
                fragmentView?.name?.setText("Hello, Anonymous")
            else
                fragmentView?.name?.setText("Hello, $username")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
    })
```

[image]

This is my content to code

```
package com.example.videoapp.Model

data class ContentDTO(var explain : String? = null,
                      var imageUrl : String? = null,
                      var uid : String? = null,
                      var userId : String? = null,
                      var username : String? = null,
                      var timestamp : Long? = null,
                      var favoriteCount : Int = 0,
                      var favorites : MutableMap<String,Boolean> = HashMap()){
    data class Comment(var uid : String? = null,
                       var userId : String? = null,
                       var comment : String? = null,
                       var timestamp : Long? = null)
}
```

This is my code where I can upload the pics. I have taken a little bit of help from the internet to do that. I am trying to display the name here but it's returning nothing

```
val storageRef = storage?.reference?.child("images")?.child(imageFileName)
storageRef?.putFile(photoUri!!)?.continueWithTask { task: com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task<com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ->
    return@continueWithTask storageRef.downloadUrl
}?.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
    val contentDTO = com.example.videoapp.Model.ContentDTO()

    //Insert downloadUrl of image
    contentDTO.imageUrl = uri.toString()

    //Insert uid of user
    contentDTO.uid = auth?.currentUser?.uid

    //Insert userId
    contentDTO.userId = auth?.currentUser?.email
    contentDTO.username = auth?.currentUser?.displayName

    //Insert explain of content
    contentDTO.explain = addphoto_edit_explain2.text.toString()

    //Insert timestamp
    contentDTO.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

    firestore?.collection("images")?.document()?.set(contentDTO)

    setResult(android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK)

    finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead :

```
 val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(auth?.currentUser?.uid)
    reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
           for(snapshot in dataSnapShot.children){
          val username = 
               snapshot.child("username").value.toString()
            if (username == null)
                fragmentView?.name?.setText("Hello, Anonymous")
            else
                fragmentView?.name?.setText("Hello, $username")
        }        
                     }
          

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
    })
```

Comment: No sir it is not working it's returning "Hello null"

Comment: I have made an edit to my post , can you try again the new code now !

Comment: Sir when I am writing "for(snapshot in dataSnapShot)" then its returning error "For loop range must have an iterator method"

Comment: sorry my mistake buddy , you have to add .children to datasnapshot in the for loop  , i editted the text   , check it out again

Comment: No sir still its returning me nothing

Comment: can you go to the Cancelled method , and log the error you re getting there to be understand under what is going on , log the error and paste it here

Comment: Sir errors are not getting upload in the comment as its too long

Comment: 2020-07-13 17:42:07.648 1977-2321/? E/ModuleIdSetter: exception when setting module id
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
        at com.google.android.chimera.config.ModuleManager.getCurrentModule(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
        at aewd.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):4)
        at aewg.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):9)
        at aeso.a(Unknown Source:0)

Comment: if you re fetching single values from a node , i d suggest you try the forsignalvaluelistener , change the only the listener and see if it works

Comment: Sir I have editted and added  some more details in the question. Plz check it

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your database, the key of all `User` objects that are stored within `Users` node, are **not** added using the `UID` that comes from the authentication process, those key as generated with the `push()` method, because all of them start with `-`.

The most appropriate solution might be to change those keys and get then the data accordingly. To add a `User` object, you should some lines of code that looks like this:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val usersRef = rootRef.child("Users")
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(user)
```

To display the name of the logged-in users, simply use the following lines of code:

```
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String::class.java)
        Log.d("TAG", name)

        //Do what you need to do with the value of name
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
usersRef.child(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: No sir codes are not working. Its returning nothing

Comment: In that case, please add a screenshot of your database to see the actual UID and not those pushed IDs, and also please edit your question to see the changed code you are using.

Comment: Sir I have added the screenshot of realtime database

Comment: You didn't. I can still see the old one. Please the one where you have used the UIDs and not those pushed IDs.

Comment: Hi, bhupen! Have you tried my solution in my answer above?

Comment: Sir I have editted and added  some more details in the question. Plz check it

Comment: That info is not helping. I asked you to add a new screenshot of the database with the changes that you made.

Comment: No but can you tell me if I can get the user name from the code which I have edited

Comment: No,  you cannot. You should use the solution in my answer and it will work 100%. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: No sir its not working. Its returning me "full name" which is the text I have given to my text view

Comment: Ok if its not working ,can u tell me how can I get the email id of the user who post their pics in place of name

Comment: That's a totally different question. For that please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: No sir I have still not find the solution of my question